# API JSON Response serialize to throw custom message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers, devise-token-auth

I am using devise token auth gem along with active model serializer to authenticate, which sends response like

```
{

  "status": "Success",

  "message": "User Created Successfully",

  "data": {

    "id": 9,

    "tokens": {

      "cUZCQrKCPQCijIjCWZI4mA": {

        "token": "$2a$10$9/ZKX7KmH4sLLdp19R331.E9BLInpnXCkJCX0xffJSHpTsu0/X.UK",

        "expiry": 1554720926

      }

    }

  }

}
```

But I am primarily looking to get something like :-

```
{

  "status": "Success",

  "message": "User Created Successfully",

  "data": {

    "id": 9,

    "token": "$2a$10$9/ZKX7KmH4sLLdp19R331.E9BLInpnXCkJCX0xffJSHpTsu0/X.UK"

  }

}
```

I tried using JSON Parse , tried fetching the last token but since the name is unknown as it is randomly generate, I am unable to do so.
How can i go about to achieve this?

Edit :-
User Serializer :-

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :tokens
end
```

Comment: Can you add your user serializer code to your question?

Comment: Edited  the post with the user serializer.. this is the basic one which returns the given results. I have moved back to the original until i get a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for posting your code. Could you try this?

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :token

  def token
    tokens = DeviseTokenAuth::TokensSerialization.load(object.tokens) # This gives you a hash
    tokens['YOURCLIENTID']['token']
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

You need the clientid, which is the key to the hash.
Also, the gem generates the token using JSON.generate. So you can [deserialize using load](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/f929fb458012a91474f92cd948739cea98bcb419/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/tokens_serialization.rb).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Nope this Returns 
```{
    "status": "Success",
    "message": "Successfully Logged In.",
    "data": {
        "id": 24
    }
}```

Comment: YES, Now it returns. token : null

Comment: Actually what i believe is happening is, It is stored into the db as a string :tokens and thus active model serializers  returns the tokens string and not token, I was thinking of a possible way to get the token before resources are saved to the db probably?

Comment: the client id is randomly generated from devise token auth gem and is a variable at each request.. how can i get the variable client id using deserialize?